# MongoDB: Mapping without reduce?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, view

I would like to create a map and query it. I'm coming from CouchDB, which allow this with views. **It something like that possible with MongoDB and is incremental Map/Reduce the right thing?**

Example: Take some documents and emit per todo a row with date after processing it and the query the result.

Document:

```
{
   name: "Max",
   todos: [
      {
         title: "Bring milk home.",
         isImportant: true,
         date: 1502557780
      }
   ]
}
```

Sample mapping function:

```
function() {
   for (var i = 0; i < this.todos.length; i++) {
      if (this.todos[i].isImportant) {
         emit(this.todos[i].date, {title: this.todos[i].title})
      }
   }
}
```

Output:

```
{
   key: 1502557780,
   value: {title: "Bring milk home."}
}
```

Querying the output:

```
db.collection.find({key: { $lt: 1502557785 }}, ...
```

Actually, I would like to do some more complex processing in the mapping function than just checking the existence of the isImportant key. So a aggregation pipline of more complex query seems not to be right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MongoDb you can use [*Aggregation Pipeline Operators*](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate(    
    [
        {
            $unwind: "$todos"
        },
        {
            $match: {
                "todos.isImportant": true
            }
        },
        {
            $project: {
                key: "$todos.date",
                value: { title: "$todos.title" }
            }
        },
        {
            $match: {
                key: { $lt: 1502557785 }
            }
        }
        // And so on ...
    ]
);
```

---

Another way is to use *[Map-Reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/map-reduce/)* like this:

```
db.runCommand({ 
    mapReduce: "c",
    map: function () {
                for (var i = 0; i < this.todos.length; i++) {
                    if (this.todos[i].isImportant) {
                        emit(this.todos[i].date, {title: this.todos[i].title})
                    }
                }
            },
    reduce: function (key, values) {
                return values;
            },
    out: { "inline" : 1},
    query: {},
    sort: {},
    limit: 100,
    inputDB: "Test",
 });
```

Comment: Yes, that's indead a way realize the example above in MongoDB. Acutally, I would like to run a map-like function on each document for more complex modifications.

Comment: @Bernd If you want more complex modifications; So you can use `mapReduce` something like my example in answer ;).